# How to reply to a Twitter conversation via email?

Tags: twitter, email

Is there a solution that makes it possible to reply to a Twitter conversation using email?

Ideally, I would like to directly respond to the email notifications as shown below:

[image]

Comment: For those wondering, Twitter doesn't seem to support this natively. So you must use a 3rd-party solution like below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You may try [Tweetymail](http://tweetymail.com/). I haven't used it myself though, but based from its features I think this is the solution to your problem.

> - **Send emails** to tweetymail in order **to tweet** and use Twitter
> - Automatically **receive** emails containing **tweets, mentions,** or Twitter    search results
> - Receive detailed notifications for new followers and direct messages

If you have already created your account, just send your tweet to `tweet@tweetymail.com` and place your tweet in the e-mail body.

Check the [user guide](http://tweetymail.com/userguide) for more info.

Comment: Tweetymail shut down at some point after this answer was posted.